# Edit Update DatagridView VB.Net (No Database)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Good day everyone.
I need your help in this project I am into (a Visual Basic program with no database.) It just contains a Datagridview, a Textbox, and three buttons (an "Add" Button, a "Edit" and an "Update" Button).

1 . Is there any way (like using "for loop") to automatically assign `DataGridView1.Item("item location")` to the one edited and be updated?

2 . Or is it possible to just click an item in the Datagridview then it will be edited at that without passing it to a Textbox, and to be updated at that.

Comment: Please read the [help on formatting posts](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and then use the [edit] link to clean up your question so that it is readable.

Comment: sorry for that Coder Hawk. uhm, wanna help?

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Comment: Hello, as you asked before.
>> Or is it possible to just click an item in the Datagridview then it will be edited at that without passing it to a Textbox, and to be updated at that.

It can, just said not readonly, but i'm not sure it can save without database

Comment: i've posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` variable (`e` in the method stub the designer will generate for you) of the double click event of the cell has `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` properties which refer to the position of the cell you clicked.

Save those (in a class variable possibly or a local one if that's all you need) and then refer to them when you update the cell in your `DataGridView`, possibly like this `MyDataGridView.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)` or `MyDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)` where `e` is the variable from the double click event handler.

For you cell double click event you could have something like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

    Using myEditor As New frmCellEditor(Me.DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value)
        If myEditor.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = myEditor.NewCellValue
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

This will call a new instance of your editor and get a value from you. For the purpose of this demo I have made a form like this:

Public Class frmCellEditor

```
    Public NewCellValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal CurrentCellValue As Object)

        InitializeComponent()

        Me.TextBox1.Text = CStr(CurrentCellValue)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Me.NewCellValue = CInt(Me.TextBox1.Text)

        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Call Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Which just has two buttons (`Button1` = OK, `Button2` = Cancel). When you click OK, it just returns the value `1` which then gets set as the value of the cell.

This is a VERY simplistic example, but it should provide you the basics of what you are trying to do.

UPDATE:

I updated the code for the editor interface so it will include handling for passing the value back and forth from the form with your datagridview.

In your project, make a new form called `frmCellEditor`. This forms has to have two buttons and a textbox (Make sure that the programmatic names match!). Replace the code with the code listed above. You will have to add `Imports System.Windows.Forms` above the class as well.

Amend the event handler for the cell double click event of your datagrid to pass the cell value when  `frmCellEditor` is constructed (the line going `... New frmCellEditor(...)`.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. When you double-click on the cell, the arguments passed to the even handler will contain the row and column index of the cell you just clicked. You hold on to those long enough until you have written the new cell value to the datagridview (or discarded it). After that you do not need the values anymore, so you can discard them.

Comment: By the way, if all you want to do is edit a cell, there is an `EditMode` property on the datagridview, which should allow you to edit the cells just like that without having to pass the value back and forth between an external form.

Comment: i believe i'm misunderstanding indeed. this is all alien language to me. sorry bro. i hope you code provide some lines of code or stuff to demonstrate what you mean, if that's okay.

Comment: yes, im familiar with the EditMode, been fiddling around it and searched it around. seen it at datagridview event as  Private Sub DataGridView1_EditModeChanged. but it requires some coding and i don't know how. :(

Comment: OK, added a sample which should show you one possible way of doing this.

Comment: sorry for being noob, i was about to comment when i saw "enter 15 characters" as caption below the the comment box, so i deleted one of my comments thinking i might get more space for further comments. fail. anyway, i did what your code, placed them specifically under their specific events. then i realized they won't be passing anything to the Textbox to be edited. anyway, i tried to run it and when i click a cell, a new form will be displayed with all the contents of the original form. like a clone of it. i have no idea what's happening.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer again. I really don't understand what you mean when you say you get a second copy of your own form being displayed... If you follow my instructions it will work. If you still can't get it to work, then I'm sorry, but I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

How many columns does your DataGridView has?
Based on how you populate your DataGridView, I'll assume only 1.
Declare this on top of your form

```
Dim i as Integer
```

On your btnUpdate_Click Event (Just combine your Edit and Update button into One)

```
SELECT CASE btnUpdate.Text
    Case "Update"
         With DataGridView1
              'Check if there is a selected row
              If .SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
                   Msgbox "No Row Selected for Update"
                   Exit Sub
              End If
              i = .CurrentRow.Index 'Remember the Row Position
              Textbox1.Text = .item(0 ,i).value 'Pass the Value to the textbox
              .Enabled = False 'Disable DataGridView to prevent users from clicking other row while updating. 
              btnUpdate.Text = "Save"
         End With
    Case Else 'Save
         DatagridView1.Item(0,i).Value = Textbox1.Text
         btnUpdate.Text = "Update"
END SELECT
```

Comment: @RedJohn Ruben's code should do what you want without having to pass data between forms. If yo can't understand his code and make it work, then you are really trying to do something that's too complicated for you at the moment. Start with something more basic and then work your way up. And also have a look at this http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-vbnet maybe it will make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who contributed to finding answers for this thread. I have not used your solutions for now (maybe some other time). After some research, I've found an answer for problem 2 (more user friendly at that):

> 2 . Or is it possible to just click an item in the Datagridview then
>   it will be edited at that without passing it to a Textbox, and to be
>   updated at that.

Here's what i did:
in Private Sub Form1_Load, just add:

```
yourDataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
```

in Private Sub yourDataGridView_(whatever event here: DoubleCellClick, CellContentClick, etc.) add:

```
DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).[ReadOnly] = False
DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)
```